# Mac - Android Running Intel Version of Emulator

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

I have a Mac Book Pro - Intel i7. I am trying to create a AVD with the accelerated Intel Options but i get the following error every time i open the AVD.

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'AVD_for_Nexus_5_by_Google'
emulator: Failed to open the hax module
HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
```

AVD Settings

[image]

Comment: Are you sure! you have done installation of HAXM from extras directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Such error: Windows Solution**

Install the HAXM Driver by running "IntelHaxm.exe". It will be located in one of following locations.

..Android\android-sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager
..adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager

Go to the directory of extras and run the installation of HAXM. It will solve your problem.

**Such error: Mac Solution**

- Go to this [link](http://software.intel.com/en-us/android).
- Choose the Intel HAXM installer package for your platform.
- Extract the installer and follow installation instructions for your
  platform.

Comment: Thanks! It works for me. perfect solution in windows :)

Comment: @Harsha M V 
Go to http://software.intel.com/en-us/android.
Choose the Intel HAXM installer package for your platform.
Extract the installer and follow installation instructions for your platform.

Comment: Also do not forget to install any hotfixes that are available for the MAC platform